# How do I get the number of XML child nodes in Haxe Script?

Tags: xml, haxe

How do I get the number of XML child nodes in Haxe Script?

In AS3, I would write node.children().length().

Suppose in Haxe, I have:

```
var node = FastXML.parse("<node><hello>Hi</hello><world/></node>");
```

node in this case has 2 children.  How do I obtain this in Haxe?

Answer (score 1):

Since [Xml](http://api.haxe.org/Xml.html) itself is an iterable of its child nodes, we can use [Lambda.count](http://api.haxe.org/Lambda.html#count).

```
using Lambda; //Static Extension http://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var xml = Xml.parse("<node><hello>Hi</hello><world/></node>");
        var node = xml.firstChild(); //<node>
        trace(node.count()); //2

        var fast = new haxe.xml.Fast(Xml.parse("<node><hello>Hi</hello><world/></node>"));
        var node = fast.node.node; //<node>
        trace(node.x.count()); //2
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working.  Possibly, because I'm using the FastXML class that came with as3hx.

But I found another way:  node.descendants().length();

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
node.descendants().length();
```